# Cannot add new issue to Jira via REST API

Tags: post, jira, jira-rest-api

I am unable to create the custom field using Jira rest API, Code below:

```
curl -D- -u abc:1234 -X POST  https://*******.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue --data '
{
    "fields": {
        "project": { 
            "key": "HELLOWORLD"
        },
        "summary": "Test-RestAPI",
        "description": "Creating Task using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
        "issuetype": {
            "name": "Task"
        },
        "customfield_10200": { "name": "ABC" },
        "customfield_10300": { "name": "ABCD" }
    }
}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Error Below:

```
{"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"customfield_10300":"Operation value must be a string"}}
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
"customfield_10300": "ABCD"
```

Answer (score -1):

According to [this document](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/?_ga=1.258260236.729769110.1485941845#api/2/issue),  If a field is not configured to appear on the create screen, then it will not be in the createmeta, and a field validation error will occur if it is submitted. If you want to create a custom field, you need to use **POST /rest/api/2/field** as per mentioned in this part of the [API documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/?_ga=1.221484574.729769110.1485941845#api/2/field-createCustomField).

Please note that, you can create custom field based on predefined JIRA custom field types.

Comment: Yes the field is already added but it is locked, Any idea how i can unlock it.. tried googleing it but can't reach anywhere :(.. I am using Jira cloud, so cant make any changes into database I have already seen this link [Jira - help](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-unlock-a-locked-field-779158866.html)

Comment: What do you mean by it's locked?! :-)

Comment: Could you please open the link and you will be able to see an image that shows the locked fields in there, let me know in case of more details :)

Comment: Sorry Mukul, please be more specify about which link you mean :-)

Comment: [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-unlock-a-locked-field-779158866.html) -- Please refer this link, Apologies for not explaining it properly. The issue is i have added a field with name - "Approver" to my issue list, but when i am creating a new issue I am unable to see that field listed there, when i went to field configuration i saw that the field was locked, As I am using jira cloud I was unable to find much on the issue. May be you can help on this :)

Comment: Well no one can help other than Atlassian Support Mukul :-) Cloud has lots of restrictions mate.

Comment: Yeah, only that is the option left now :( .. anyways thanks for your help, you were very helpful..!! :)

Comment: No worries mate :-)